# What can i do to resize a UIView to fit its subviews?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, sizetofit

I know that i must use -sizeThatFits: method and override it in superView. But, what should I do in this method? should I only calculate new size of my View, or I should send some messages to its subViews? Maybe -sizeThatFits: and -sizeToFit: messages? And, when and how I should "say" to my superView that it is time to Resize its frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding the first part of your question:** Your `-sizeThatFits:`implementation should never call `-sizeToFit:`on subviews.  The former is a method to *calculate* a size for your view (without changing it at all), while the latter actually *changes* your view's size.

You can definitely forward `-sizeThatFits:` calls to your child views, if that will help in your view's size calculations.

**Regarding the second part of your question:** you shouldn't be telling your superview when to resize your view, normally.  It should be the other way around: a controller or a parent view should be the one to attempt a resize on your child view in the first place.

From Apple's documentation: `sizeThatFits - Implement this method if you want your view to have a different default size than it normally would during resizing operations. For example, you might use this method to prevent your view from shrinking to the point where subviews cannot be displayed correctly.`

What the docs are saying is that if your `-sizeThatFits:` implementation never returns a frame below a certain size: that size will basically become your view's minimum size during resize operations.

**PS:** since in the topic of your question you're asking how to resize a view to fit it's contents - you should be using sizeToFit for that purpose.  You'll need to implement that method yourself for custom views.

Comment: This is correct. You should never really set your own frame except when setting up a reasonable default in `-init` like some UIKit controls do. The view controller sets your frame and you lay everything out in `-layoutSubviews` when it gets invoked. If the parent wants to know what size you need for a given height or width, you implement sizeThatFits. Sharing code between `-layoutSubviews` and `-sizeThatFits` is where things get icky.

Comment: Thanks! But, if I resize my subView with animation _(Resize in the subView method. I want create custom view, that will be my subView, containing UILabelView and UITableView below label, that will change its rows count)_, should I send message -sizeToFit to its superView after all?

Comment: No, a view should not know about its superview directly (or send it messages) - that would be a bad design choice.  Could you clarify what you mean by "if I resize my subView with animation"?  More specifically: what method would you call for that purpose, and what object would be the sender of the message?